# How to fix my date values from changing when exporting from database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date, time

I am trying to create a time sheet database which records the date and time a user clocks in and clocks out I have set up my Postgresql table and have it display through react correctly however when I export the data to Excel the time in the date value moves 4 hours behind and shifts the day to one day before. How can I fix this?

I have already tried using different data types such as date, timestamp and timestamptz however all of them end up giving me the same outcome.

My current punch in Date column for SQL looks like:

```
ADD COLUMN in_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
```

The table displayed on my web app screen will show the date 2019-05-08 00:00:00 
However when I export to Excel the same column shows 2019-05-07 8:00PM.

I know that the values are being set back 4 hours due to timezone change from UTC to my Local time however I am not sure how to fix this. I have tried a lot. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's code language you using export to Excel?

Comment: Javascript. I'm running my program through React JS

Comment: Can you show code that get data from DB and export excel?